# Oracle generic function to read different cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to fetch cursor data into array or table with dynamic cursor parameters ?

*Example* : We have 3 function fct1(), fct2(), fct3(). They all return a CURSOR with different data (from different table) and their size is between 20 and 100.
I'd like to call this 3 function with a generic function, fill a VARCHAR2 array and for example print this array.

I've found out how to fetch cursor into a VARRAY or VARCHAR2 but then you need to specify which cursor value you add into the array.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CURSOR_EXAMPLE AS


    FUNCTION fct1 (param01 IN VARCHAR2) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS
    my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
        OPEN my_cursor FOR 
            SELECT a, b, c FROM table1, table2, table3;
        RETURN my_cursor;
    END fct1;


    FUNCTION fct2 (param01 IN VARCHAR2) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS
        my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
        OPEN my_cursor FOR 
            SELECT q, w, e, r, t, y FROM table4, table5;
        RETURN my_cursor;
    END fct2;
    
    
    FUNCTION fct3 (param01 IN VARCHAR2, param02 IN VARCHAR2, param03 IN VARCHAR2) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS
        my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
        OPEN my_cursor FOR 
            SELECT x, y, z FROM table6, table7, table8, table8;
        RETURN my_cursor;
    END fct3;
    
    
    PROCEDURE generic_function (fct IN NUMBER, param01 IN VARCHAR2, param02 IN VARCHAR2, param03 IN VARCHAR2, cursor_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    AS
    BEGIN
        IF fct = 1
            cursor_out := fct1(param01);
        ELSE IF fct = 2
            cursor_out := fct2(param01);
        ELSE IF
            cursor_out := fct3(param01, param02, param03);
        END IF;
        
        LOOP
            FETCH cursor_out INTO
                -- HERE DEPENDING ON fct1, 2 and 3 add cursor_out variable into a VARRAY (extend it as needed)
                
            
            EXIT WHEN cursor_out%NOTFOUND;
            
        END LOOP;
        
        -- PRINT VARRAY
        
    END generic_function;


END CURSOR_EXAMPLE;
```

Comment: It would help us to visual what you're trying to achieve if you provide some sample code. Also, what version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: There's no easy way for generic algorithms in PL/SQL due to it is statically typed. What do you want to achieve with this approach? Your data flow upwards will process only structured result anyway

Comment: Using Oracle 11g DB.
I'm trying to have a generic method that could read different cursor (I'll add some code)

Comment: Something similar may be possible using [polymorphic table functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/polymorphic-table-functions-18c), but these require 18c or later, and you'd need a corresponding set of pipelined table functions to convert the ref cursors to nested table collections.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to devise a dynamic means of discovering what columns are contained within the cursor.

There is a way, but it involves using `DBMS_SQL` and once you convert the cursor to a `DBMS_SQL` cursor, you will have to use `DBMS_SQL` all the way as you process the records.

Here is an example of a test function that can return one of four different cursors, without static defined types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_test_cursor (n in number default 1) return SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
  c SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   IF n = 1
   THEN
      OPEN c FOR SELECT 'A' f1, 'B' f2 FROM DUAL;
   END IF;

   IF n = 2
   THEN
      OPEN c FOR SELECT cast(1.234 as number(6,2)) n1, cast(12 as number(8)) n2, 'C' f3 FROM DUAL;
   END IF;

   IF n = 3
   THEN
      OPEN c FOR select * from all_objects;
   END IF;
   
   if n = 4
   then
      OPEN c FOR select sysdate as current_dt from dual;
   end if;
   return c;
END;
/
```

Now, we can use the `DBMS_SQL` package to first convert the cursor from a **REF CURSOR** to a **cursor number** using `dbms_sql.to_cursor_number`.
Once we do this, we can use the rest of the `DBMS_SQL` API to inspect the cursor and do work on its data.

```
declare
  cur sys_refcursor;
  c number;
  col_cnt     INTEGER;
  rec_tab     DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
  --
  -- This is a crude helper procedure to display one line of "DESCRIBE" output
  --
  PROCEDURE print_rec(rec in DBMS_SQL.DESC_REC) IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad(rec.col_name, 41) || ' ' ||
    rpad(case when rec.col_null_ok then ' ' else 'NOT NULL' end, 8) || ' ' ||
    case when rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR or rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 then
      'VARCHAR2(' || rec.col_max_len || ')'
    when rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_CHAR then
      'CHAR(' || rec.col_max_len || ')'
    when rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_NUMBER then
      case when rec.col_precision = 0 and rec.col_scale = -127 then 'NUMBER'
      when rec.col_scale = 0 then 'NUMBER('||rec.col_precision||')'
      else 'NUMBER(' || rec.col_precision || ', ' || rec.col_scale || ')'
      end
    when rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_DATE then
      'DATE'
    else
      'UNKNOWN'
    end);
  END;
begin
  cur := test_cursor(3);
  --
  -- Convert the REF_CUR to a cursor number
  --
  c := dbms_sql.to_cursor_number(cur);
  --
  -- Use an API call to describe the columns
  --
  DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(c, col_cnt, rec_tab);
  --
  -- Now loop through the columns and show them
  --
  dbms_output.put_line('Name                                      Null?    Type');
  dbms_output.put_line('----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------');
  for j in 1..col_cnt loop
    print_rec(rec_tab(j));
  end loop;
  --
  -- We can do other things at this point. 
  -- When done, close the cursor.
  --
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c);
end;
/
```

Here is the output when we pass in 3, which queries the `ALL_OBJECTS` view:

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
OWNER                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
OBJECT_NAME                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
SUBOBJECT_NAME                                     VARCHAR2(128)
OBJECT_ID                                 NOT NULL NUMBER
DATA_OBJECT_ID                                     NUMBER
OBJECT_TYPE                                        VARCHAR2(23)
CREATED                                   NOT NULL DATE
LAST_DDL_TIME                             NOT NULL DATE
TIMESTAMP                                          VARCHAR2(19)
STATUS                                             VARCHAR2(7)
TEMPORARY                                          VARCHAR2(1)
GENERATED                                          VARCHAR2(1)
SECONDARY                                          VARCHAR2(1)
NAMESPACE                                 NOT NULL NUMBER
EDITION_NAME                                       VARCHAR2(128)
SHARING                                            VARCHAR2(13)
EDITIONABLE                                        VARCHAR2(1)
ORACLE_MAINTAINED                                  VARCHAR2(1)
```

Once you are able to see what the columns of the cursor are, you are on your way to solving the problem of creating a dynamic procedure that consumes random cursors and populates arrays.

Comment: Thanks Tad for your reply, but what is the pros converting ref cursor to DBMS_SQL ?